# Drupal 7 reset password

Tags: authentication, drupal, passwords

Hello sorry if this question is duplicate but unfortunately I couldn't find answer I need. I have a problem with a Drupal 7 login, I forgot the admin password and I can't open the reset password page so I tried through the PHPmyAdmin to make changes directly on database and I used this query:

```
UPDATE users SET pass='$S$Do7UQjqtEELNccdi92eCXcVJ2KnwUeHrSbK3YhFm8oR3lRJQbMB2' WHERE uid = 1;
```

and it successfully changed my password into database, but I still can't log in to website...is there any advice for me what could be a problem?

Thanks

Comment: How did you generate the hashed password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index, you can write this code. Execute your web page.
.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);


require('includes/password.inc');

echo "Now, execute this SQL<br><br> UPDATE users SET pass='".user_hash_password('mypassword')."' WHERE uid = 1;"; 
die();
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

You can also use drush

```
drush upwd admin --password=mypassword
```

More info: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2010-12-08/reset-admin-password-in-drupal-7